# How can I unserialize this string as its showing error at point 292?

Tags: php, serialization

this is my string in serialized form.when i tried to unserialized (convert to array) the string i was given error ,please see the following serialized string

```
a:6:{s:5:"width";s:3:"614";s:6:"height";s:3:"414";s:14:"hwstring_small";s:23:"height='86' width='128'";s:4:"file";s:171:"2011/02/Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:9:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-162x160.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"162";s:6:"height";s:3:"160";}s:6:"medium";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-258x173.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"258";s:6:"height";s:3:"173";}s:5:"large";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-530x357.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"530";s:6:"height";s:3:"357";}s:12:"post-special";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-530x380.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"530";s:6:"height";s:3:"380";}s:8:"post-top";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-110x110.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"110";s:6:"height";s:3:"110";}s:9:"post-tiny";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-108x100.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"108";s:6:"height";s:3:"100";}s:9:"post-item";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-455x327.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"455";s:6:"height";s:3:"327";}s:11:"post-review";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-162x166.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"162";s:6:"height";s:3:"166";}s:9:"post-poll";a:3:{s:4:"file";s:171:"Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-285x237.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"285";s:6:"height";s:3:"237";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}}
```

i am getting error as

```
Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 292 of 2873 bytes
```

please help and tell me what is the best what to serialize the string 
below is my original array

```
array (
  'width' => '614',
  'height' => '414',
  'hwstring_small' => 'height='86' width='128'',
  'file' => '2011/02/Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok.jpg',
  'sizes' => 
  array (
    'thumbnail' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-162x160.jpg',
      'width' => '162',
      'height' => '160',
    ),
    'medium' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-258x173.jpg',
      'width' => '258',
      'height' => '173',
    ),
    'large' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-530x357.jpg',
      'width' => '530',
      'height' => '357',
    ),
    'post-special' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-530x380.jpg',
      'width' => '530',
      'height' => '380',
    ),
    'post-top' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-110x110.jpg',
      'width' => '110',
      'height' => '110',
    ),
    'post-tiny' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-108x100.jpg',
      'width' => '108',
      'height' => '100',
    ),
    'post-item' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-455x327.jpg',
      'width' => '455',
      'height' => '327',
    ),
    'post-review' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-162x166.jpg',
      'width' => '162',
      'height' => '166',
    ),
    'post-poll' => 
    array (
      'file' => 'Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok-285x237.jpg',
      'width' => '285',
      'height' => '237',
    ),
  ),
  'image_meta' => 
  array (
    'aperture' => '0',
    'credit' => '',
    'camera' => '',
    'caption' => '',
    'created_timestamp' => '0',
    'copyright' => '',
    'focal_length' => '0',
    'iso' => '0',
    'shutter_speed' => '0',
    'title' => '',
  ),
)
```

thanks

//new data
i did 171 to 169
when i json_encode('any image');
its giving `null`.

Comment: How did you serialize the the array in the first place? Using the `serialize()` function or some custom function?

Comment: No need to allow serialize/json_encode to excape/convert those special characters like ’ let it do the work, don't try to "fix" it... else you'll have to write a custome unserialize/json_decode to match

Comment: @konsolenfreddy this is string from wordpress serialize function.

Comment: Are you trying out all the serialization formats today? You could have left it at the JSON with proper ecaping instead of running into precisely those charset issues.

Comment: @user1133643   Probably it was in unicode and you've lost something during copy+paste.

Comment: @mario which serialization formats?

Comment: now i am getting new problem please see question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I unserialize this string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753573/how-can-i-unserialize-this-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make any manipulations with serialized string? Any charset encoding (jumping from UTF to ASCII and vice versa), html entities encoding/decoding or something else?
This

> s:171:"2011/02/Classis-Pallela-from-Embrujo-Flamenco-at-97-Danforth-Ave.-We’ve-picked-the-classic-version-59-for-two-made-with-the-unique-and-super-absorbent-Bomba-rice.-ok.jpg"

should be 171 characters in length between the quotes, but it is only 169 characters long. And, of course, it will throw an error in the process of unserialization.

ps: check the length of the original string with that data.

Comment: Well spotted! Any other hobbies apart from counting chars ;)

Comment: From OP's previous questions, I think he's tried to "fix" this with an str_replace() after the serialize()

Comment: Previous question probably was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029888/how-to-serialize-this-string